# Git Command that Shows My User Name and Email ~ so that I can know which account I am logged into

Tags: git, github

I have two gitHub accounts, and I would like to keep them 100% separate.  I do not want to add myself as a collaborator on either account.  Every time I push to an account, I re-configure my git user settings.

**Is there a git command in the terminal that will allow me to see which user I am currently logged-in as on my local computer?**  so that I can know if I need to reconfigure my git settings or not?

something like:

```
git user.name
```

and

```
git user.email
```

that would log:

> user: yourUserName
>   email: you@email.com

Thanks!

Comment: `git config --list`; `git config user.name`; `git config user.email`

Comment: @XavierGuihot Thank you.  That solved the problem.  I need to figure out how to search the site because I searched and was not able to find that answer.  If you have any tips, I'm happy to know them.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was git config --list
per @Xavier Guihot